# Exclude certain URLS in Django urls.py when on my test (not production) site

Tags: django, seo, sitemap, robots.txt

I run our production and test sites on Heroku.  I have a robots.txt and sitemap that I want to only run when in production (so that google doesn't start crawling our test site and penalize us on the real site for duplicate content).

The easiest solution would be something like adding a if statement to urls.py to not include /robots.txt and /sitemap.xml when on the test site.  However, I can't figure out how to do this.

I could include a different robots.txt file when on my test site that disallows crawling for any page which seems like an ok solution.   But, as we add more types of sitemaps, etc, it'd be easier to have one if/else statement in urls.py.

Anyone have an elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in that way:

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       ...
                      )

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
                            ...
                           )
```

Comment: That's a decent way.  To make this more flexible I defined some config variables in Heroku and then used them to tell my urls.py which container it was currently in.